# Creating html pages dynamically using stored templates

Tags: asp.net, html

I need to create an asp.net website which will allow the end users to select a prestored template from available templates, edit header, footer and body contents of the template and create a HTML page that will be stored in a physical folder of website with names like test1.html, test2.html, etc.

Can somebody please suggest me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can you [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) for same, First of all you can created pre-define template in your project and user can select those pre-define template and modified it in CKEditor and stored on physical location(on drive).

It's might be helpful.